# position of a text on windows form

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

I was wondering if there was a way to get a position on a known text from a window handler pointer ?

I am working on a project using C# and .NET and i need to find a position of a given text on its window

Thanks

Comment: What type of control is the text being rendered on? TextBox, Label, ...???

Comment: will the label wont provide you with location properties? Check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the prettiest, but should meet your needs:

```
    public static Point GetLocationFromHandle(IntPtr handle, string controlNameToLocate) {
        Control c = FromHandle(handle);

        if (c != null)
        {
            Control myCtrl = c.Controls[controlNameToLocate] as Control;
            if (myCtrl != null)
            {
                return myCtrl.Location;
            }
        }

        return Point.Empty;
    }
```